# Difference between deploying `index.html` vs. `npm start` for local Node project?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, npm-start, serve

I'm completely new to web programming and have a very basic `Angular.js` app in `JetBrains Webstorm` IDE.

In `Webstorm` I can right-click on `index.html` file and choose `Run/Debug` and it will launch the app in `Chrome` with the debugger attached (I have chrome LiveEdit Jetbrains extension). This created a generic `JavaScript Debug` configuration. This is nice because it launches a chrome browser running my app automatically.

[image: ich]

However, I was also able to run the app using `npm start` via `JetBrains` `npm` template. while I haven't explored it further, can probably also run the app using a `Node.js` template.

**My question is that what is the difference between these launch methods?
How would I choose one rather than the other?***

It's nice that, for example, running `index.html` directly opens a chrome tab automatically.  But what is the difference in doing this way over another?  For local development, which one is *better*?

Comment: AngularJS or Angular?

Comment: AngularJS (inherited projects in this framework)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The application development landscape has been changing continuously
> over the past few years, both on the client side (**frontend**) as well as
> on the server side (backend). On the client side, we have plenty of
> awesome new and updated JavaScript [and other scripting] frameworks;
> and on the server side, we have new architectural approaches such as
> **single page applications(SPA)**, **microservices**, and **serverless** architectures.

The `index.html` is the main root file in your front-end & `index.js` is the main starting point of your backend. When you install `Node` on machine there is an `npm` which is node package manager which can install the project libraries and packages using 'npm install' based on the information on the `package.json` file. If you look into this file there is `script` part such as this:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./index.js",
  },
```

The project command starting with `npm` such as `npm run start` or `npm run build` ... can be found and define here.

When you start with your backed it initiated your project and load required `templates`. When you using `IDE` such as `Webstorm`, `Visual Studio`, or ... they build and run your entire project. So, by initiating and serving the `index.html` just you can see a part of front-end application and this running that you can see is what 'IDE's provide for you. For better understanding this process you can open project in a simple text editor such as [Sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/3) text editor to understand the differences. So there are actually no difference in your context.

This was an general explanation that I hope could help but there are many other rooms to discuss.